# Redirect url other then root to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to do following redirects:

```
http://example.com to some static page
http://exmaple.com/<anything> to http://subdomain.example.com/<anything>
```

Currently i have this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ static/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(*)?$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which webserver you are using? `nginx`/`apache2` ?

Comment: @starkeen i have made edits, please check

Comment: @Gangaraju its apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)This will redirect the homepage of example.com to /static/index.html#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /static/index.html [NC,L]
#2)This will redirect  /anything  to sub.example.com#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [NC,L,R,NE]
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but its working opposite static page is redirecting to sub.example.com and other are not redirected to subdomain

Comment: @Sirajulhaq yes, there was a mistake in the rule above,I have a RewriteCond to exclude the page..

Comment: Now first one works and redirecting to sub domain doesn't work

Comment: I have commented all other rules, still sub domain  redirect not working.

Comment: What exactly happenes when you type the url and what url are you typing in your browser?

Comment: when i type htttp://example.com then it shows me static html page as expected but when i type http://example.com/b/w/ it redirects to http://example.com/b/w/index.php?r=something

Comment: @SirajUlhaq your other rules might be overriding this. please post your full htaccess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111212/discussion-between-siraj-ul-haq-and-starkeen).